# React use one event handler for different inputs

Tags: reactjs

How do align with DRY coding when handling onChange for an simple contact form in React application?

I would like to pass an param with the state that should be updated

For example, simply having 4 inputs [name, phone, email, text] require 4 different eventhandlers updating different states of component, which is not great.

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      type: '',
      message: '',
      name: '',
      email: '',
      phone: '',
      content: ''
    };
  }
  handleChange(e, state) {
    this.setState({state: e.target.value});
    alert(state + " with val " + e.target.value)
  }
```

This doesn't work and throwing an Cannot read property 'value' of undefined error

```
<input value={this.state.name} onChange={this.handleChange(name).bind(this)} id="firstName" name="firstName" autocomplete="off" type="text" required />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need pass argument to `handleChange` like this

```
onChange={ this.handleChange.bind(this, name) }
```

and signature for `handleChange` will be `handleChange(state, e) {}`

---

or you can use [`arrow function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

```
onChange={ (e) => this.handleChange(e, name) }
```

---

**Update**

Based on your problem description, I suppose you don't need pass additional argument, you can take input `name`(*in this case I think input name and state name can be the same*), and can do like so

```js
class Form extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    this.state = {
      // type: '',
      // message: '',
      name: '',
      email: '',
      // phone: '',
      // content: ''
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }
  
  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
  }
  
  render() {
    return <div>
      <input 
        value={this.state.name} 
        onChange={ this.handleChange } 
        name="name" 
        autocomplete="off" 
        type="text" 
        required 
      />
          
      <input 
        value={this.state.email} 
        onChange={ this.handleChange } 
        name="email" 
        autocomplete="off" 
        type="text" 
        required 
      />
          
      <p>{this.state.name},{this.state.email}</p>
    </div>
  }
};

ReactDOM.render(<Form />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: @AlexanderT. the update looks like a best and simplest solution. Thank you for help and variety of options !